# Can't insert a line in my highscore table in Java

Tags: java, insert, line

I am a beginner Java programmer. I am programming a minesweeper game and I want to insert a line in myhighscore table.
Everytime, first essai is successful but when I replay, I can't insert a line and I have an error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed

Anyone could see the problem ?

```
public void insererLigne(String texte, int numLine, int numDelLine) {

    List<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        for (int i = 1; scanner.hasNextLine(); i++) {       
            String line = scanner.nextLine();

            if (i == numLine) {
                fileLines.add(texte);
    }           
            if (i != numDelLine) {                   
                fileLines.add(line);
      }              
        }
    } 

    finally {     
        if (scanner != null) {                
            scanner.close();
       }            
    }

    PrintWriter pw = null;       
    try {          
        pw = new PrintWriter(fichier);       
        for (String line : fileLines) {        
            pw.println(line);              
        }           
    }  
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();        
    } 

    finally {           
        if (pw != null) {            
            pw.close();           
        }          
    }       
}
```

Comment: exception says, scanner is closed, could please share the code where  you declared & initialized the scanner object

Comment: And please reformat the code in your post - I suspect you don't *really* have a blank line between every line of code... (I'd also strongly recommend that you use the try-with-resource statement instead of manually closing things, and be very nervous every time your "handling" of an exception is just dumping the stack trace and continuing as if everything were fine...)

Comment: The scanner is probably a member field and closed because the first run of this method actually closes it in the `finally{}` block (!).

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala {public class dataPersist {

    private static final String nomFichier = "highscore.dat";
    private File fichier;
    private RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile;
    private Scanner scanner;

.
.
.

    public void insererLigne(String texte, int numLigne, int numSuppLigne) }

Comment: I should delete my finally block ? @user268396

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments what you should do is remove the scanner member field from the object/class itself and create a *new* scanner each time you want to read the file inside the method body. Incorporating the suggestion to use try-with-resources, you'd get something like this:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fichier)) {
// use scanner here as before
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
// do something sensible here...
// can probably ignore, no highscore file yet.
}
// no finally block needed, scanner cleaned up automatically
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fichier)) {
// use pw here as before.
}
catch(FileNotFoundException|IOException e) {
// do something sensible here. unable to write highscore file(!)
}
// no finally block needed, pw cleaned up automatically
```

EDIT: As an additional note, you should be aware that you are doing blocking IO in the AWT Event dispatch (GUI) thread. That is generally a bad idea, because it means your GUI will be blocked until the IO completes. For similar reasons, uncaught exceptions are also a very bad omen for GUI responsiveness. As a result doing IO in the GUI thread is OK for learning/toy programs but for more robust programs you should look into delegating the work of reading/writing the highscore to a different thread. (Swingworker or ExecutorService would be a good fit.) This concern is not specific to Java, it translates into similar concerns with many common UI toolkits (such as Qt or GTK) and other event-loop based libraries in a variety of languages.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is a class level variable, and you are closing it in the finally block, thus second time its not able to read.

Solution: there are two options, either use what user268396 suggested or do not close the scanner in the finally block, instead have a separate method, which should get invoked once entire file is read.